# simplify dynamic jquery selector

Tags: jquery

Given the following table

```
<table id="t1" border="1">
  <thead><tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr></thead>
  <tfoot><tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></tfoot>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select first and third column in `<tbody>` only. Note that selection of multiple columns may varies for a huge table. The following expression return the correct selection in this example.

```
var a = $('#t1 tbody tr td:nth-child(1), #t1 tbody tr td:nth-child(3)')
```

but

```
var b = $('#t1 tbody tr td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3)')
```

`b` will returns selection include `<tfoot>`. More over for `b` result, first element is missing?!

What is the most simplest way for `var a` selection above for a X-number of columns. 
E.g:

```
Select columns [1,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kkgian/4kdNt/2/

TIA

Answer (score 1):

For selecting multiple columns in the same row:

```
$('#t1 tbody tr').find("td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3)");
```

For selecting columns at a regularly spaced interval:

```
$('#t1 tbody tr td:nth-child(3n)'); //should get column 3, 6, 9, ...
```

As a corollary of that, to get every other element starting at 1 (in your case 1 and 3):

```
$('#t1 tbody tr td:nth-child(2n+1)'); //should get column 1, 3, 5, ...
```

For selecting columns [1,4,5,6,7,8,9]:

```
var cols = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$('#t1 tbody tr td').filter(function(idx) {
    return $.inArray(idx+1, cols)!=-1;
});
```

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is a method for reducing the set of matched elements to those you want to use -- in this case to a column index specified in your array. Any value for which the expression returns `true` is included. **Note:** Within `.filter()` idx is 0-based, so add 1 if the values in your array are intended to be 1-based.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ -- of course `:nth-child(odd)` also works

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    rows = $('#t1 tbody tr'),
    tds = $('td', rows).map(function() {
        if ( $.inArray($(this).index(), arr) >= 0)
            return this;
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4kdNt/7/)**

Comment: `$.inArray()` doesn't return a boolean, it returns the index at which the value is found or -1 (all truthy except for index 0). Also, using `$(this).index()` returns the index of the element in the matched set -- meaning in this case [0,1,2] repeated 5 times. Since '1' is the only value actually in the array, the others return -1 which is truthy - so they pass. The '1' is at index 0, so it's falsey and fails -- which is the only reason this method actually returns columns 1 and 3, pure coincidence :/